# Mocked $location.path is returning server

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I'm testing this particular function:

```
function apiInjector($location, $cookies) {
    var apiVersion = 1, baseUrl;
    console.log('Host: '+$location.host());

    if($location.host() == 'localhost') {
      baseUrl = $cookies.get('API_HOST') || 'http://localhost:5000';
    } else {
      baseUrl = 'productionURL';
    }
    if(!baseUrl)
      throw('Invalid host defined');

    function isApiRequest(url) {
      return url.substr(url.length - 5) !== '.html';
    }

    return {
      request: function(config) {
        if(isApiRequest(config.url)) {
          config.url = baseUrl + '/' + apiVersion + '/' + config.url;
        }
        return config;
      }
    };
}
```

As you can see it makes use of $location.host to determine what the host is. I've created a mock to use so I can control the flow when it comes to the if-else statement:

```
    var apiInjector, $location;
    var mockedLocation = {
        host: function() {
            return 'localhost';
        }
    };
    beforeEach(module('flowlens'), function($provide) {
        $provide.value('$location', mockedLocation);
    });
    beforeEach(inject(function(_apiInjector_, _$location_) {
        apiInjector = _apiInjector_;
        $location = _$location_;
    }));

    describe('apiInjector',function(){ 
        it('should be defined', function() {
            expect(apiInjector).toBeDefined();
        });
        it('should expose a request function', function() {
            expect(apiInjector.request).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
```

But when I call the function (apiInjector.request) I always see **server** printed when i insert a console.log ($location.host()) in the actual code (see above). What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

This is what is printed when i print the result of apiInjector.request.

```
Object{url: 'productionURL/1/dashboard'}
```

But based on the code above and assuming that the host() function returns **localhost** (which it doesn't it returns **server**) it should print either the result of the $cookies.get or the http://localhost:5000

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say 'server come back' what exactly is returned? I also cannot see the function apiInjector.get in your code

Comment: Sorry i meant calling the .request function. I'm not worried too much about the cookies part just yet as I'm sure it will follow the same process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load your module within the function passed to the beforeEach block then pass the function using `$provide` as a callback to module:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    module('flowlens', function($provide) {
        $provide.value('$location', mockedLocation);
    });
});
```

Or you could write it like this:

```
beforeEach(module('flowlens'));
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('$location', mockedLocation);
}));
```

Alternatively, [sinon](http://sinonjs.org) has some good options for spies, stubs, mocks, etc. I've used it to mock `$location` like:

```
var location,
    locationStub;

beforeEach(inject(function($location) {
    location = $location;
    locationStub = sinon.stub(location, 'url');
    locationStub.returns('some/fake/url');
}
```

Comment: The most annoying part about testing for me is that I'm along the right line but just don't seem to wrap things up correctly. Your answer above worked - my apiInjector was successfully defined and I know the $location.host() is returning what I want it to. I also had to add a url: function() {return null} to the mocked object as it was complaining that it didn't exit. Thanks again

Comment: No problem. Yes unit tests with mocha/jasmine can be difficult to get right even though the syntax looks simple on the face of it